# Python Boto List Storage Devices Attached to Instance

Tags: python, amazon-ec2, boto, volumes, mounted-volumes

I'm using Python 2.7 and Boto.latest.

I'm creating a dynamic inventory script and I would like to list the storage devices that are attached to each instance

Example:

```
ID: i-3rblah
Storage:
-  /dev/sda 
- /dev/sdb
- /dev/sdc
```

Tried:

```
for reservation in reservations:
  for i in reservation.instances:
    volumes = conn.get_all_volumes(filters={'attachment.instance-id': i.id})
    print i.__dict__
    print volumes.__dict__
```

So I have some volume info, but not what the VolumeID is mapped to.

Comment: You want list of volume id attached to each instance or the list of instance attached to a volume id?

Comment: list of volumes attached to each individual instance. thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want the `BlockDeviceMapping` for the instance.  Based on your example above the following should find the `block_device_mapping` for the instance which is a dictionary.  Each key in the dictionary is a device name and the value is a `BlockDeviceType` object which contain information about the block device associated with that device name.

```
for reservation in reservations:
    for instance in reservation.instances:
        bdm = instance.block_device_mapping
        for device in bdm:
            print('Device: {}'.format(device)
            bdt = bdm[device]
            print('\tVolumeID: {}'.format(bdt.volume_id))
            print('\tVolume Status: {}'.format(bd.volume_status))
```

This should print something like:

```
Device: /dev/sda1
    VolumeID: vol-1d011806
    Volume Size: attached
```

There are other fields in the `BlockDeviceType` object.  You should be able to find more info about that in the Boto docs.

Comment: Thank you. Now that I have an idea of what to look for, I am on my way to getting all the wanted info.

Answer (score 0):

To get all the volume id's atttached with an instance-:

```
inst=conn.get_all_instances()

    for reservation in inst:
      for i in reservation.instances:
        volumes = conn.get_all_volumes(filters={'attachment.instance-id': i.id})
        print "This instance:",i.id," is attached to ", volumes
```